# How to change global two dimensional array of structs inside a function on C?

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I wanted to change a global array using pointers, but it doesn't seem to work. I would appreciate more effective ways to make the job done.

Here is a piece of code, it shows Segmentation fault exception when it reaches a line with `->`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MWIDTH  512
#define MHEIGHT 512

typedef struct
{
    int artifactValue;
    int artifactType;
    int occupation;
} sTile;

sTile *tile[MHEIGHT][MWIDTH];

FILE* f;
int height, width, ii, jj;
int array[MHEIGHT][MWIDTH];

void getDimensions()
{
    if ((f = fopen("C:\\C projects\\amazons\\state.txt", "r")) == NULL)
        exit(1);
    if (fscanf(f, "%d%d", &height, &width) != 2)
        exit(1);
    if (height < 1 || height > MHEIGHT || width < 1 || width > MWIDTH)
        exit(1);
}

void getBoard()
{
    for(jj=0; jj<height; jj++)
        for(ii=0; ii<width; ii++)
        {
            fscanf(f, "%d", &array[jj][ii]);

            if (array[jj][ii] < 10)
            {
                tile[jj][ii] -> artifactValue = 0;
                tile[jj][ii] -> artifactType = 0;
                tile[jj][ii] -> occupation = array[jj][ii];
            }

            else if (array[jj][ii] < 100)
            {
                tile[jj][ii] -> artifactValue = 0;
                tile[jj][ii] -> artifactType = array[jj][ii] / 10;
                tile[jj][ii] -> occupation = array[jj][ii] % 10;
            }

            else if (array[jj][ii] < 999)
            {
                tile[jj][ii] -> artifactValue = array[jj][ii] / 100;
                tile[jj][ii] -> artifactType = array[jj][ii] % 100 / 10;
                tile[jj][ii] -> occupation = array[jj][ii] % 100 % 10;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: `sTile *tile[MHEIGHT][MWIDTH];` creates a matrix of pointers, each pointer in the matrix can point to an sTile object, however no memory was reserved to store the actual sTile objects, and these pointers are not initialized to point somewhere in the code-snippet you posted, and using them is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sTile *tile[MHEIGHT][MWIDTH];
```

This is 2D array of pointers. You need to allocate the memory for each pointer in this array.

```
for(jj=0; jj<height; jj++)
    for(ii=0; ii<width; ii++)
    {
        fscanf(f, "%d", &array[jj][ii]);
        tile[jj][ii] = malloc(sizeof(sTile));
        ...
    }
}
```

Do not forget to free each pointer when you do not need to use them.

Comment: If the board is square, I always recommend to use a one-dimensional array of size height * width. That saves allocation loops and memory freeing issues.